# Restricting the number of elements a data constructor can have

Tags: haskell

I am writing an ADT in Haskell which represents a hand of cards. My problem is that I would like to restrict the number of `(Suit,Face)` which represents a card to 5 which represents a hand.

```
data Card = Hand [(Suit,Face)]
```

What I tried to do was this but it does not work.

```
data Card = Hand [(Suit,Face),(Suit,Face),(Suit,Face),(Suit,Face),(Suit,Face)]
```

My question is: how do i restrict the number of tuples to 5?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd like to add that if you use a solution based on 5-tuples (as suggested in the other answers), you can still have all folding/traversing functions you need. In particular, first define

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable

data Tuple5 a = Tuple5 a a a a a
```

and define [folding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) and [traversing](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html) operations on it:

```
instance Traversable Tuple5 where
    traverse f (Tuple5 a b c d e)
            = Tuple5 <$> f a <*> f b <*> f c <*> f d <*> f e
instance Foldable Tuple5 where
    foldMap = foldMapDefault
instance Functor Tuple5 where
    fmap    = fmapDefault
```

Then, you can have

```
data Hand = Hand (Tuple5 Card)
```

and fold/traverse the structure using any methods from `Foldable`/`Traversable`/`Functor`.

---

**Update:** Recently I created a small library [tuples-homogenous-h98](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuples-homogenous-h98) that defines `newtype` aliases for homogenous tuples such as

```
newtype Tuple5 a = Tuple5 { untuple5 :: (a,a,a,a,a) }
```

and adds proper `Traversable`, `Foldable`, `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
data Card = Hand (Suit, Face) (Suit, Face) (Suit, Face) (Suit, Face) (Suit, Face)
```

?

Or, if you really want to use a list (I mean, if you wanted 15-card hands, my suggestion becomes very silly), you can keep `data Card = Hand [(Suit, Face)]` and then tell users to *not* use the constructor, and instead provide a "smart constructor" like

```
fromList :: [(Suit, Face]) -> Maybe Card
fromList xs 
        | length xs == 5 = Just (Hand xs)
        | otherwise      = Nothing
```

You could then also leave the constructor itself available with a warning like "use only if you guarantee that the supplied list contains precisely 5 elements".

By the way: Isn't naming the data type `Card` and the constructor `Hand` a bit counterintuitive? I think the data type should be called `Hand` in your case. `Card` is a nice alias for a `Suit`-`Face` pair, so you could do `type Card = (Suit, Face)` and `data Hand = Hand [Card]`.

Comment: It would make it more difficult for me to iterate because putting it in a list gives me access to functions

Comment: Yeah, and it's only nice with small hands. I've added a suggestion for how you can keep using lists.

Comment: Talking about smart constructors,How do i restrict the user from not using the original data constructor.

Comment: One common approach is to simply not [export](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html) it from your module. In your case, I would probably make it available with an explicit warning telling people (and yourself) to only use it for lists you know have precisely 5 elements. I'm guessing it could be useful in many cases when you know very well that you're giving 5 elements and want to avoid the `Maybe`.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain this concept to me.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a type for Cards and a Hand type with five Card elements:

```
type Card = (Suit, Face)
data Hand = Hand Card Card Card Card Card
```